# Java 2D Game Lighting, 'problem' with alpha

Tags: java, 2d, lighting

Thanks for reading!

I always wanted Lighting in my simple 2D java games, and I finnaly came up/found some code that I implemented in my game. It's all working but the area that isn't lighted is completely black, I wanted a more see through grayish darkness. So I thought it would be simple, I changed the alpha from 255 to 200 but nothing changed. I changed it to 1, this created the effect I wanted, but also created a funny other effect where the light would stay for a bit when I moved the light, kinda like a trail. But anyway, how do I change the pitch black to have some more alpha?

Light.java:

```
private BufferedImage image;
private int x;
private int y;

public Light(int x, int y, int radius, float luminosity) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    image = new BufferedImage(radius * 2, radius * 2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

    for(int i = 0; i < radius; i++) {
        double luma = 1.0D - ((i + 0.001) / radius);
        int alpha = Math.min((int)(255.0D * luma * luminosity), 255);
        g2.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, alpha));
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2.drawOval(radius - i, radius - i, i * 2, i * 2);
    }
}

public void render(Graphics2D g2) {
    g2.drawImage(image, (x - image.getWidth() / 2)  - Game.instance.cam.getX(), (y - image.getHeight() / 2) - Game.instance.cam.getY(), image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
```

LightHandler.java:

```
public BufferedImage lightMap = new BufferedImage(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

private ArrayList<Light> lights = new ArrayList<Light>();

public void makeLightMap(BufferedImage lightMap) {
   Graphics2D gl = lightMap.createGraphics();
   gl.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 255));   // This is the place I thought I should change the Alpha
   gl.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
   Composite oldComp = gl.getComposite();
   gl.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstOut);

   for(Light light : lights) light.render(gl);

   gl.setComposite(oldComp);
   gl.dispose();
}

public void addLight(Light light) {
    lights.add(light);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it at my own! For everyone needing a solution: I added another type of light to my game: A square with a fixed alpha, this did exactly what I wanted!